# CG-Boost - Apple_Knife Tutorial - seams? and darkness?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I am currently doing the CG-boost blender 2.8 series and find an issue with texture paint being a nearly black texture, but still a texture, even on the saved image and in the shading editor, but the file image used is bright?

Also, the apple has the texture painted dark colour, but the seems show through like pen lines, it's very obvious, 4 seems.  Not mentioned in the tutorial or seen?
Why do I have this issue if I followed the tutorial? Note I altered the bleed to max and it did nothing I really notice.

Here is a picture link, it is set to 4px bleed, that seems fine in cycles, but eevee is seemed, and the texture painted extra dark compared to original texture used?

[image: pic]

Comment: I didn't follow those tutorial, so please share the .blend file or some screenshots

Comment: Please present your problem with screen shots and settings so we can help figure out what you need - a description of a tutorial's results doesn't help us since we all are not following the same tutorial. Also maybe see if CGBoost has a support thread on that tutorial for questions since they might be better able to answer specifically.